# How many ways can three employees each take a day off next week if they cannot all take the day off on the same day?

Tags: combinatorics

Three employees are to take vacation next week. However, they cannot all take the day off on the same day. How many ways can they take the day off next week? There are five days in the next week that they can take the day off.

My attempt:

Employee 1 will have $5$ choices , employee 2 will have then $4$ choices and the last employee will have $3$ choices so $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$.

Comment: Employee 1 will have 5 choices , employee2  Will have then 4 choices and the last employee will have 3 choices so 5*4*3= 60 .

Comment: Matter of interpretation. It could be $2$ gone on Wednesday is OK. Then there are $120$ ways.

Comment: The it should be 100

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic question.You should study the Probability basics thoroughly first and also should make some attempts of your own.
Since there are $3$ employees and $5$ working days in the week. First Employee has $5$ choices as he can take leave on any day. Second employee has $4$ choices left as he cannot take leave on the same days taken by first employee. Similarly third employee has only $3$ choices.So the answer will be:

$5×4×3 = 60$

Comment: You have not considered the possibility that two of the three employees are absent on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "they cannot all take the day off on the same day" clearly means that **all three** cannot take off on the same day.

- All take off on different days: $5\cdot4\cdot3 = 60$
- Two take off on the same day:
  (Choose day when two take off)$\times$(Choose two people)$\times$(Off day for the third) $= \binom51\binom32\times4 = 60$
- Thus $60+60 = 120$ ways

Answer (score 0):

The first has 5 options...then the second has 4 aand the third has 3 options..hence the total number of ways should be 
$$5×4×3=60$$

Comment: You have not considered the possibility that two of the three employees are absent on the same day.